# Messages while migrating Ghost Blog from SQLite to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ghost-blog, ghost

I tried to migrate ghost blog from SQLite to MySQL. I have completed the configuration as mentioned [here][1] I am getting following messages on command line. Is it correct or there is some issue in my config ?

```
$ npm start --production

> ghost@0.11.10 start /Ghost/Ghost
> node index

WARNING: Ghost is attempting to use a direct method to send email. 
It is recommended that you explicitly configure an email service.
Help and documentation can be found at https://docs.ghost.org/v0.11.9/docs/mail-config.

[ { sql: 'show tables like ?',
    output: [Function: output],
    bindings: [ 'settings' ] } ]
{ method: 'first',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ 'databaseVersion', 1 ],
  __knexQueryUid: '676a8f35-f680-4194-8214-0b9b54ba2kkk',
  sql: 'select `value` from `settings` where `key` = ? limit ?' }
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [],
  __knexQueryUid: 'a882bfa0-8b4d-4f04-a638-0c971ee9kkkk',
  sql: 'select `settings`.* from `settings`' }
[ { sql: 'show tables like ?',
    output: [Function: output],
    bindings: [ 'settings' ] } ]
{ method: 'first',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ 'databaseVersion', 1 ],
  __knexQueryUid: '984e224e-9909-434e-b1d2-0c971ee9kkkk',
  sql: 'select `value` from `settings` where `key` = ? limit ?' }
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [],
  __knexQueryUid: 'f6b8795b-7af2-4b39-a18d-0c971ee9kkkk',
  sql: 'select `permissions`.* from `permissions`' }
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ 'activeTheme', 1 ],
  __knexQueryUid: 'd5c924a7-4020-4cff-8a8d-0c971ee9kkkk',
  sql: 'select `settings`.* from `settings` where `settings`.`key` = ? limit ?' }
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [],
  __knexQueryUid: '6f7eb24c-e3c7-4197-a308-0c971ee9kkkk',
  sql: 'select `settings`.* from `settings`' }
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ 'installedApps', 1 ],
  __knexQueryUid: '0bf06724-21e3-46b0-9b9e-0c971ee9kkkk',
  sql: 'select `settings`.* from `settings` where `settings`.`key` = ? limit ?' }
{ method: 'update',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: 
   [ '2017-07-03 12:39:55',
     1,
     25,
     'installedApps',
     'app',
     '2017-07-03 12:51:14',
     1,
     'f45a2c39-8be1-4858-a213-0c971ee9kkkk',
     '[]',
     25 ],
  __knexQueryUid: '018b0cc4-f1c5-4e95-9dd0-0c971ee9kkkk',
  sql: 'update `settings` set `created_at` = ?, `created_by` = ?, `id` = ?, `key` = ?, `type` = ?, `updated_at` = ?, `updated_by` = ?, `uuid` = ?, `value` = ? where `id` = ?' }
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ 1499086274940 ],
  __knexQueryUid: 'aa394d2a-e425-4652-ab83-0c971ee9kkkk',
  sql: 'select `accesstokens`.* from `accesstokens` where `expires` < ?' }
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ 1499086274941 ],
  __knexQueryUid: '1a374b81-1c98-4d01-81d0-0c971ee9kkkk',
  sql: 'select `refreshtokens`.* from `refreshtokens` where `expires` < ?' }
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ 'ghost-scheduler', 1 ],
  __knexQueryUid: '0a851e78-5a7e-422a-9b5a-0c971ee9kkkk',
  sql: 'select `slug`, `secret` from `clients` where `clients`.`slug` = ? limit ?' }
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ 'scheduled' ],
  __knexQueryUid: '0663f666-fe0f-4115-91ce-0c971ee9kkkk',
  sql: 'select `id`, `published_at`, `created_at` from `posts` where `posts`.`status` = ?' }
Ghost is running in production... 
Your blog is now available on http://localhost:2368 
Ctrl+C to shut down
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [],
  __knexQueryUid: '287f9644-4baa-476a-84a7-0c971ee9kkkk',
  sql: 'select `settings`.* from `settings`' }


  [1]: http://www.techtrekking.net/how-to-migrate-ghost-blog-from-sqlite3-to-mysql/
```

Please note that blog us working fine but I am worried about these messages 1). if I have done any wrong config or 2). These extra display might impact server performance ?

Do I need to make any changes other than what is mentioned at http://www.techtrekking.net/how-to-migrate-ghost-blog-from-sqlite3-to-mysql/

Comment: It looks like your program is set to log SQL queries and operations to the console. That seems excessive for a production system. You should look for the log configuration and try to change it. The instructions you showed have `debug: true` in a database config file. Try editing that to change it to `debug: false`.

Comment: Thanks this does solves my problem.